# Open access table from word

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-word

I'm looking for a way to open an access table directly from a word document. So a little like:

```
Sub nieuwsdm()

Dim pptapp As PowerPoint.Application
Dim ppt As PowerPoint.Presentation
Set pptapp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
Set ppt = pptapp.Presentations.Open("pres1.ppt")
```

But then with an access file. Anybody a clue on how I can fix this?

Comment: Are you trying to *open* an Access table or *query* an Access table? There's a big difference between the two. :)

Comment: Im trying to open a table @BK201

Answer (score 1):

Possibly you could use something like: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/193716
How to Use a Microsoft Access Query or Table as a Word Data Source
 To use a Microsoft Access query or table as a Word data source, follow these steps:

1.If you want to use the results of a Microsoft Access query or table as your data source in a Word mail merge, in the Mail Merge Helper (on the Tools menu, click Mail Merge), click Get Data and then click Open Data Source.
 -or- 
If you want to insert the results of a Microsoft Access query or table in a Word document, in the Database dialog box (on the Database toolbar, click Insert Database), click Get Data.

NOTE: To access the Database toolbar, on the View menu, point to Toolbars and then click Database.
 2.In the Open Data Source dialog box, follow these steps:a.Change the Files of Type box to "MS Access Databases."
b.Click to select your Microsoft Access database file.
c.Click to select the Select Method check box.
d.Click Open.

3.In the Confirm Data Source dialog box, select "MS Access Databases via DDE (*.mdb)," and then click OK.

NOTE: If "MS Access Databases via DDE (*.mdb)" is not available, you will need to remove and then reinstall Microsoft Access 97 for Windows.
 4.In the Microsoft Access dialog box, select the Queries tab or the Tables tab.
 5.Select the query or table you want to use, and then click OK.

NOTE: On the Queries tab, the Create Link check box is selected by default. This option creates a link to the Microsoft Access database query. Select this check box to always retrieve the most up-to-date version of any of the listed queries. To ignore changes to the original query instructions, clear the Link to queries check box.
 6.Word will return the results of your Microsoft Access query or table to your Word document.

If you are using mail merge, Word will prompt you with the following message:

Word found no merge fields in your main document. Choose the Edit Main Document button to insert merge fields into your main document.
 Click Edit Main Document and continue your mail merge as usual. 
-or- 
If you are inserting database information, in the Database dialog box, click Insert Data. In the Insert Data dialog box, select either All to insert all of the results of the Microsoft Access query into your Word document or select From and specify which records you want to insert into your Word document.

NOTE: In the Insert Data dialog box, the "Insert data as field" is not selected by default. If selected, this option inserts the data into the table as a field. Select this check box if you want to update the data in your Word document whenever the data source changes.

Comment: Kindly edit your answer to show a *solution* or an *explanation* before this gets downvoted. Simply posting a link and asking him if he's read it **does not qualify** as a proper answer. It would qualify better as a comment instead.